# is it possible to insert auto-generated data into a column which is not an identity

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have one table like notification configuration , i want to insert the values in three columns named process-code, id,journal-id.
i need to insert following values.
process code = 9001.
id = should be auto-generated start from 16000.
journal-id from another table.

how it can be possible, looking for help.
Please suggest.

Comment: for id column if you had 16100 as 100th record and then this record will be deleted you want the next will be 16100 or it doesn't matter if it will be 16101?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to insert data into auto-generated column .as it is itself auto increment right ...